# Eclipse's export wizard not generating proper apk(complete size)

Tags: android, eclipse, export, apk

My application's debug apk(one in bin folder) size is 25.8 MB, I'm not using proGaurd as of now, I have multiple libraries such as Facebook, Twitter, Google play services, Vuforia, and few other graphics related jars. So my problem is when I'm generating release version apk using export wizard I'm not getting correct apk file size. Everytime I generate apk for release version  the size is different( like 19MB, 21MB, 23MB ,22MB,25MB). When I install this apk on device it is crashing. I have 8GB of RAM, I cleaned project before starting process, closed all running applications except eclipse , I also run CC cleaner and started eclipse from cmd prompt with 'eclipse-clean'  command but still I wasn't successful to generate correct apk.

Any suggestions to solve my problems will be appreciated.

Comment: Check once the pro-guard file,

Comment: are you exporting lib with it?

Comment: Yes,all files including libs are exported.